# PHP code for orbited comet server and stomp

Tags: php, comet, stomp

After long searching of comet server, i choose orbited comet server.

I have to build a real-time chat system in PHP using Orbited Comet Server and Stomp PHP client.

It does not handle hundreds or thousands of simultaneous connections.

How could i solve this problem? Is there any other library to add for fix this problem?

Thanks.

My Regards

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a problem I have wrestled with for quite a while in PHP, specifically for the same kind of usage scenario.  The only possible solutions I have come up with so far are these:

1) Implement another comet server other then orbited, and build it with that kind of load in mind, with an eye toward using the cloud for quick server standup.

2) using a stable messaging fabric such as the ones already implemented in Java in order to add to the performance side of things, while having to handle it properly with my own php library.

Both of these solutions have their own ups and downs, but I feel that in the end, implementing such a server in PHP, or with the existing oss solutions that I know of, would be futile for high volume communications.